# Populate an arbitrary concrete IEnumerable, from another IEnumerable

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable

I'm writing some reflection code. Ah well.

---

I have an `IEnumerable<TData>` values object, and an `Expression<Func<TInstance, IEnumerable<TData>>>` representing a property whose type implements (but is not *declared* as) `IEnumerable<TData>`.

e.g. I have a property declared as:
`public SomeProp List<String> {get;set;}`, a values object `new[] {"a", "bee", "sea"}`, and the expression `obj => obj.SomeProp`

I have successfully written the code that extracts the information:

> the concrete implementation of `IEnumerable<>` for `SomeProp` is `List<>`

and thus I can call `values.ToList()` on my `IEnumerable<string>` values object and successfully assign the result to the property.

For any particular implementation of `IEnumerable<>` I could manually write code to detect that implementation, and code to create a concrete object that satisfies it.
Indeed I currently have a small mapping dictionary, which covers some cases:

```cs
new Dictionary<Type, Func<IEnumerable<TProp>, IEnumerable<TProp>>>
{
    { typeof(List<>), (vals) => vals.ToList() },
    { typeof(IList<>), (vals) => vals.ToList() },
    { typeof(Collection<>), (vals) => new Collection<TProp>(vals.ToList()) },
    { typeof(ICollection<>), (vals) => new Collection<TProp>(vals.ToList()) },
};
```

Naturally, that doesn't even cover most of the *common* cases, let alone covering every possible case!

---

**Is there any way to write reflection code that will take an arbitrary "values" `IEnumerable<T>`, and a target concrete `IEnumerable<T>`, and create that concrete instance from the values?**

*It seems a little optimistic, but I figured it was worth asking :)*

Comment: The question is, what do you want to do when it's not possible? Because there will be cases where an interface doesn't have any concrete implementation.

Comment: @CorentinPane That does sounds like an interesting case, if it exists, but I don't understand why you think it exists? Can you give an example of an Interface that has no concrete implementation?

Comment: @jdweng I've no idea what question you're trying to answer ... but that definitely isn't an answer to *this* question. Apart from anything else ... we only have 1 `IEnumerable` object, and we don't know anything about the objects that it contains.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica--Brondahl-- I can create an interface ``IArbitrary<T> : IEnumerable<T>`` which doesn't have any concrete implementation. What happens if you try to create the "target concrete ``IEnumerable<T>``" behind it? Also, you're assuming that this concrete type can be constructed from an `IEnumerable<T>`, so what if this is not the case?

Comment: @CorentinPane oh ... yeah ... of course you could. (I'd only been thinking in terms of .NET framework types, in which case such an interface wouldn't exist since it would be pointless) Cool. I think that pretty canonically proves that the task must be is impossible.

Comment: @CorentinPane do you want to post that as an answer. I think "considering the problem in _this_ light makes it clear that the challenge is logically impossible to solve" is a perfectly good answer to have on SO.

Comment: i'm already working on it:)

Comment: You said "Populate an arbitrary concrete IEnumerable, from another IEnumerable".  So you have two lists (they may be the same list).  So which items in first list populate the 2nd list?  You need a mapping between the two lists and the mapping must be done with the JOIN.

Comment: @jdweng ... Did you consider that it might be useful to actually *read* the question, rather than just the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** In the general case, this won't be possible. In the end, this is just a matter of interfaces not being directly constructible.

**Within the .NET framework types**

If your target type is indeed a concrete type like `List<>` or `Collection<>`, then it will be possible to create an instance out of its `Type` object. You still have to assume that there exists a constructor that accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` as first and only argument. This is not the case even with common framework types:

```cs
Type[] types = { typeof(List<string>), typeof(IList<string>), typeof(Collection<string>), typeof(ICollection<string>) };
IEnumerable<T> values = new List<T> { /* ... */ };
foreach (var type in types) {
    var concreteInstance = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>) })?.Invoke(new object[] { values });
    // Succeeds for List<>.
    // Fails for IList<> as not a concrete type.
    // Fails for Collection<> as no constructor accepts IEnumerable as first argument.
    // Fails for ICollection as not a concrete type.
}
```

**General case**

Let's define the following interface:

```cs
interface IArbitrary<T> : IEnumerable<T> { }
```

As a matter of fact, there is no concrete implementation of this interface so far. So creating a "target concrete `IArbitrary<T>` from an `IEnumerable<T>`" won't be possible with reflection code, no matter how hard you try.